# facebook url for open authentication login

Tags: facebook, oauth

First let me say I really sorry for asking a question about facebook.

I'm trying to use open authentication to login in users on my site but I cannot find where to register my application/website on facebook. What is the url?

## update

I've done that but get this:

our account must be verified before you can take this action. Please verify your account by adding your `<a onclick="var newwindow = window.open(&quot;http:\/\/www.facebook.com\/confirmphone.php&quot;,&#039;confirm_phone&#039;, &#039;height=350, width=520, left=100, top=100, resizable=yes, scrollbars=no, toolbar=no, status=no&#039;);if (newwindow) &#123; newwindow.focus();&#125; else &#123; alert(&quot;A pop-up blocker may be disabling the the mobile verification window.&quot;);&#125;">mobile phone</a> or <a href="https://secure.facebook.com/cards.php" target="_blank">credit card</a>.`

## update

If you get that link you need to paste this into the URL if it doesn't popup.

http://www.facebook.com/confirmphone.php",'confirm_phone&%23039;,%20&%23039;height=350,%20width=520,%20left=100,%20top=100,%20resizable=yes,%20scrollbars=no,%20toolbar=no,%20status=no&%23039;);if%20(newwindow)%20&%23123;%20newwindow.focus();&%23125;%20else%20&%23123;%20alert("A%20pop-up%20blocker%20may%20be%20disabling%20the%20the%20mobile%20verification%20window.");&%23125;

## update

Then I have to join this group

http://apps.facebook.com/developer/

And when I do it says it's no longer there.

## update

Ok finally got to a link somehow after register my phone.

http://developers.facebook.com/setup/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[www.facebook.com/developers](http://www.facebook.com/developers)

Goto this URL and register your profile as a developer first. Then create a new application.
If you are able to do that successfully, then comment back for the further steps.

Comment: turn your pop-up blocker off. its happening because of that.

Comment: they have recently changed the url of the developers page. best of luck for your application. dont forget to put further comments for any kind of help.